# How can I insert an image with zenity?

Tags: zenity

I have tried `--window-icon` in zenity by giving the image path, but it is not working... The code I tried is:

```
zenity --window-icon "/home/pavan/Downloads/badge.png" --title "Search Box" --text "Type to search.." --entry --width 2000
```

I also tried `--window-icon=/home/pavan/Downloads/badge.png`, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Thanks Florian , but still it is not working

Answer (score 1):

I dunno about Zenity but it's brother Yad may work, http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/45/idpl/17003956/numer/1/nazwa/yad

Run the below commands:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get -q -y update
sudo apt-get -q -y install yad
```

You can add an image with the `--image='C:\this_is_sparta'` option.

YAD follows the same syntax and everything but is far more powerful.